# WSO2 API development by API portal

Tags: wso2

I have one generic question about WSO2 development. Is there any possible to develop simple or complex API development only by  WSO2 Portal itselt without any IDE like Eclipse

Comment: Hi Mohan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you specify which product you are talking about, and what exactly you want to develop?. The answer for Enterprise Integrator would be completely different than for API Manager.

Comment: do you want to implement some business functionality on the WSO2 API Manager itself?

Comment: Thanks for you valuable comments. @ophychius yes. I want to develop WSO2 Enterprise Integrator by using WSO2 EI portal. Is it possible? Since we could see all the components like services,proxies,sequences etc., in their portal.

Comment: @gusto2 Yes, I mean WSO2 EI web portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible. You can create an API in the management console of the Enterprise Integrator / Enterprise Service Bus. This is great for quickly building or testing something.

You can do this by Going to API's in the menu on the left once having logged into the management console and simple clicking Add API

[image]

However in the long run you might want to develop using an IDE or some text editor and then deploying to the Integrator. This makes it easier to control deployments, Versions of API's etc/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possible to develop simple or complex API development only by WSO2 Portal itselt without any IDE like Eclipse 
>    I want to develop WSO2 Enterprise Integrator by using WSO2 EI portal. I

It is not really clear what level of services you have in mind.

What concerns of creating service mediations (implementing integration patters), you can do everything from the admin console (create a proxy or api). I do it often for prototyping. Everything what you could see to be done in the WSO2 Developer Studio (Eclipse plugin), you can do manually too.

> what would be the best way to develop complex API?

What is a complex API for you?  The ESB (EI) is not intended to do very complex business logic, execute long running tasks or .. well.. anything you rather may create a separate service or application. You wouldn't want to build an accounting application with it. Not that it is not possible, but not really feasible.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your detailed answer. Lets take this scenario 

-  We want to develop around 10 API's with some complex business logic that includes operation like external service , REST API, DB calling, data transformation,structural mapping,XSLT,aggregation etc.,

- Once it's developed then deployed all these API's and completely hand over to Client from us(development team).

- In future, they(as Client) will able to do some few enhancements,changes sometimes adding new API's only by WSO2 EI web portal. But they won't be using any IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the API publisher UI you can create APIs.

Comment: It is important to understand that this is not actually developing a full API. Instead you are connecting to an existing backend API/Service.

Comment: Ok thanks @ophychius. I don't want use any IDE to develop a full API.Then what would be the best way to develop complex API?